# svg2png performance

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm having difficulties with the speed of svg2png and wondering if there was any way to improve it. I'm using D3 to create a Radar Chart. This is all rendered by Node.js in a jsdom. The resulting SVG is converted to a PNG using svg2png. The purpose of doing this is to then insert the image into reports which are provided to the end user. The same javascript which renders the radar chart is used within the app (without node.js) and works very quickly.

Using .NET core 2.1 and Node.js v8.11.2

Time taken to convert the svg to png is approximately 2-3 seconds.

Invocation of node services;

```
public async Task<string> GetRadarChartAsync(dynamic options)
{          
  return await _nodeServices.InvokeAsync<string>("./wwwroot/js/node-radar-chart.js", options);
}
```

Which is being called like so and the base64 image extracted.

```
Task<string> result = (Task<string>)mapped_function.DynamicInvoke(objects.ToArray<object>());
string img_base64 = result.Result;
```

The javascript wrapper looks like this;

```
module.exports = function(callback, options, data) {

   const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><div id="body" class="radar-chart"></div>`); 

   var options1 = {
       window: dom.window,
       selector: '.radar-chart',
       data: JSON.parse(data.radar)
   }

   var options_combined = Object.assign(options1, options);

   var chart1 = new RadarChart(options_combined);

   // Convert SVG to PNG and return it to controller
   var svgText = chart1.html();

   svg2png(Buffer.from(svgText))           
      .then(buffer => buffer.toString('base64'))
      .then(buffer => callback(null, buffer));

}
```

**UPDATE 14/8/18**

Previously incorrectly labelled this issue as an invocation issue between node and .NET Core 2.1. Further investigation revealed that svg2png is causing the problem.

**FURTHER UPDATE**

Issue is likely due to svg2png utilising PhantomJS. Proposed idea was to allow svg2png to use the same PhantomJS instance over multiple calls, but there is no development on this issue as yet. See [svg2png github](https://github.com/domenic/svg2png/issues/71).

I'll have to deal with my speed issues until a better solution presents itself.

Comment: When you profiled it, where did the bottleneck seem to be?

Comment: @mjwills. After the callback in the js and (after the svg2png was complete) and receiving the result via img_base64 = result.Result

Comment: Using the same setup with the performance issues as described above, looking forward to a solution on this. In my case there are instances where more than 50 charts get generated when a Node JS instance is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried out the [NodeServices samples on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/master/samples/misc) (especially the server-side rendering one) then the invocation time was 1 second minimum when using .NET 2.0. When I tried it with .NET 2.1 I think it decreased to like 100ms or less if I remember correctly. So it's possible that the NodeServices invocation time got a huge improvement from 2.0 to 2.1.

If it is not possible to upgrade then maybe you could refactor so that you need to invoke NodeServices only once.

Comment: I was able to and have just upgraded to .NET Core v2.1. Unfortunately it hasn't improved performance, or if so very marginally. There is still a 2-3 second wait whilst the image is being returned from the Task.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used svg2png but I see that you do `buffer.toString('base64')` which probably is not too efficient. I would imagine this happens:

1. The whole buffer is read to the end and converted at the same time to Base64, and Base64 in itself is not very efficient when it comes to size on disk (as far as I know).
2. Then this whole conversion is moved from Node to ASP.NET and I guess there could be some serialization going on here which will be slow with huge Base64 content(?).

I would look into using **streams** on both sides as that's what is usually used when it comes to media files.

Comment: Love the idea, but I can't seem to get a stream returned from node.js

Comment: I found an example here (under "Example 2: Getting a stream of binary data from Node"): https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices#invokeasynct

Comment: Hey @PeterHenry did you look into it (my previous comment)?